# Insert 0-5 images into a column that doesn't distort the row?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb, twitter-bootstrap-4

I need to add a series of images to rows, but I'm having difficulty with scaling (source assets are large by default) and it not pushing out other columns. I'm using bootstrap 4 and trying to make it work but it's not happening for me.

Here is what I'm starting out with looks wise and what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

I'm trying to just iterate through my object and span into a single `td` for each time an attribute matches a string and insert an `image_tag` when it finds a match. Here is my code and what it currently looks like with this code implemented.

```
#erb file
<tbody id="hits">
  <% @objects.each do |obj| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to obj.title, obj_path(obj) %></td>
      <% if obj.packages.any? %>
        <% obj.packages.each do |p| %>
          <td>
              <span><%= image_tag "img1.jpg", :class => "imgrow"  if p.someattribute === "attr1"%></span>
              <span><%= image_tag "img2jpg", :class => "imgrow"  if p.someattribute === "attr2"%></span>
              <span><%= image_tag "img3jpg", :class => "imgrow"  if p.someattribute === "attr3"%></span>
              <span><%= image_tag "img4jpg", :class => "imgrow"  if p.someattribute === "attr4"%></span>
              <span><%= image_tag "img5jpg", :class => "imgrow"  if p.someattribute === "attr5"%></span>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= obj.capacity %></td>
      <td><%= obj.started_at.strftime('%A, %B %e, %Y at %l:%M %p') if obj.started_at? %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><%= link_to "Load More", objects_path, class: "load-more" %></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is my style sheet

```
#CSS
.imgrow {
  display:block; width:100%; height:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image]

It sort of scales down (images are much larger by default) and if you look at the border color shows that not all images scale the same way.

What am I doing wrong and how do I go about achieving my goal?

Comment: I wanted to ask you if you have an update. Thanks Fabrizio

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I added my own answer to the post that you can look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get close enough to what I wanted.

```
.obj-image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height:15%;
  width:15%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the different images are just scaling based on the width of the container?
They are `100% width` of the container, if the glass is an image `100px height` and `100px width`, then the `span` will be `100px width`, while if the dollar is `100px height` and `140px width` then that conteiner span will be `140px width`.

Maybe this is the reason they are looking different?

Because you apply this css:

```
.imgrow {
  display:block; width:100%; height:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I use upload with `carrierwave` and you can use image versions. It uses `imagemagick`  gem to scale images correctly based on your width/height settings.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions

https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick
https://www.gra2.com/article.php/using-rmagick-imagemagick-rails